# Wamp : You don't have permission to access file.html on this server

Tags: php, apache

I tried to create a virtualhost to access to my local website using wampserver, but i get a `403 Forbidden` when i'm trying to access to the webpage :

I put the following line in my browser :

```
mywebsite/html/start.html
```

[image]

Here is the content of my httpd-vhost file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mywebsite
    DocumentRoot "D:\pathToMySite"
    <Directory "D:\pathToMySite">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I put the alias also in my host file :

```
127.0.0.1    mywebsite
```

Comment: You are missing slashes in the paths

Comment: @PeeHaa It's a bad copy/paste, i fix it

Comment: also the slashes should be a forward slash (linux/unix way)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will share my httpd.conf for AMPPS under windows(should be very similar to wamp)

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    <Directory "{$path}/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "{$path}/www/cgi-bin/"
    DocumentRoot "{$path}/www"
    ErrorLog "{$path}/apache/logs/error.log"
    CustomLog "{$path}/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory "F:/www">
        Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
        AllowOverride All
        Order deny,allow
        allow from All
    </Directory>
    DocumentRoot "F:/www"
    ServerName site1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I also use host file for local DNS

```
127.0.0.1    site1.com
```

hope that helps !